# R: codify a variable based on preavious observation and by other variable

Tags: r, for-loop

considering the following data:

```
Var1 Var2  Target
A      0         no
A      250       no
A      0         si
A      0         si
B      0         no
B      0         no
B      0         no
B      250       no
C      0         no
C      250       no
C      0         si
C      250       no
```

and look at the variable called Target. I need to reproduce it with the same values.

The condition to obtain "si" or "no" is the following:

for the same level of Var1 (e.g A) if Var2=250 and the nexts are =0 then Target=si

I made this code:

```
df$Target <- NA

for(i in unique(df$Var1)){

   subset.data.frame(df, Var1==i)
   for(n in 1: length(df$Var1))

     df$Target <-

        ifelse(df$Var2[n]==250 && df$Var2[n+1]==0 && df$Var1[n+1]==df$Var1[n], "si", "no"))
```

But I get Target=si only if the next Var2=0. 
Instead, as described in the dataset above, all observations with Var2=0 after a 250 have to be Target=si.

Could you help me to solve the problem, please?

Thank you,
Andrea

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    group_by(Var1) %>%
    mutate(Target = ifelse(cumsum(lag(Var2, default=0) == 250) > 0
                           & Var2 == 0, 'si', 'no'))
```

#### Result

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   Var1 [3]
     Var1  Var2 Target
   <fctr> <int>  <chr>
 1      A     0     no
 2      A   250     no
 3      A     0     si
 4      A     0     si
 5      B     0     no
 6      B     0     no
 7      B     0     no
 8      B   250     no
 9      C     0     no
10      C   250     no
11      C     0     si
12      C   250     no
```

#### Explanation

We use `dplyr` to group `df` by the levels of `Var1`, then for each group `cumsum(lag(Var2, default=0) == 250) > 0` tells us for every row in that group if *any* previous observations of `Var2` within that group were 250 and `Var2 == 0` tells us if the current observation of `Var2` is 0. If both of those conditions are `TRUE`, we code `Target` as "si", otherwise we code it as "no"

#### Data

The data I started with for `df` are

```
structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    Var2 = c(0L, 250L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 250L, 0L, 250L, 0L, 
    250L)), .Names = c("Var1", "Var2"), row.names = c(NA, -12L
), class = "data.frame")
```

#### Comparison to akrun's Solution

The output of [arkun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun)'s solution is below so you can determine which approach is more appropriate for your problem.

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   Var1 [3]
     Var1  Var2 Target
   <fctr> <int>  <chr>
 1      A     0     si
 2      A   250     no
 3      A     0     no
 4      A     0     no
 5      B     0     no
 6      B     0     no
 7      B     0     si
 8      B   250     no
 9      C     0     si
10      C   250     no
11      C     0     si
12      C   250     no
```

Comment: Really great solution using dplyr, I never used it. Thahk you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Var1) %>%
   mutate(Target = replace(Target, Var2==0 & lead(Var2, default = Var2[n()])==250, 'si'))
```